# AttributeError: 'Ghostscript' object has no attribute '_instance'

Tags: ghostscript, python-3.8

In my university semester project we are attempting to use ghostscript on some PDF files, however when we try to run our code, we get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Ghostscript' object has no attribute '_instance'
```

We have tried various attempts to fix this, however have not found a solution yet. The only part in which we are using ghostscript is the following code:

```
ar = ["-sDEVICE=pdfwrite", "-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress", "-dQUIET", "-dBATCH", "-dNOPAUSE", "-dPDFSETTINGS=/printer", "-sOutputFile=" + os.path.join(filepath, file), os.path.join(filepath, file)]
gs = ghostscript.Ghostscript(*ar)
del gs
```

We are using Python-3.8 and PyPi Ghostscript 0.7.

Has anyone else encountered this error or does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: There is no Ghostscript version 0.7. The current version is 9.55.0, version 1.0 was released back in the 1980s, before Python, so I very much doubt you are using 'Ghostscript version 0.7'. I suspect you are using the PyPI Python bindings for Ghostscript 'python-ghostscript' (which **is** at version 0.7) . Have you actually installed Ghostscript ? The bindings won't do you any good at all if the library isn't present.

Comment: Yes that is correct, I am using PyPi ghostscript 0.7, apologies. I have installed Ghostscript yes. I believe I just found the solution. Apparently it is important in which order you give the arguments, so by moving "-sDEVICE" and "-dPDFSETTINGS" behind "-dNOPAUSE" it works.

Comment: For plain Ghostscript that would make no difference at all, obviously I don't know what the Python glue code is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the order in which you pass the arguments is important. So instead of having:

```
ar = ["-sDEVICE=pdfwrite", "-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress", "-dQUIET", "-dBATCH", "-dNOPAUSE", "-dPDFSETTINGS=/printer", "-sOutputFile=" + os.path.join(filepath, file), os.path.join(filepath, file)]
```

We now have:

```
ar = ["-dQUIET", "-dBATCH", "-dNOPAUSE", "-sDEVICE=pdfwrite", "-dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress", "-dPDFSETTINGS=/printer", "-sOutputFile=" + os.path.join(filepath, file), os.path.join(filepath, file)]
```

This solved the issue for us.

Comment: You can't have PDFSETTINGS twice (as you have). The latter overwrites the former. beyond that the order has some minimal importance but the changes you;ve made should make no difference. Of coruse I can't speak for what the Python interface code may be doing.